# How do I dump columns without datatype in SQLmap?

Tags: sqlmap

I would like to what's the command to dump only columns names, not data type. And also is it possible we can search in data? Like fetch the column data having @gmail.com or word 'admin.

Answer (score 0):

`--columns` option can be used to enumerate the columns

`--where=constraint` option can be used to search for specific data (similar to SQL's where clause)

Ex: `--where="mail='abc@gmail.com'"` 
mail is the column name and abc@gmail.com is the keyword to be searched

Refer to Usage Section [here](https://github.com/sqlmapproject/sqlmap/wiki/Usage)